# Is there a way to implement similar Raise Property Changed for VS2015?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Seems I have syntax errors in VS2015 for the code below.
The error sounds like:

> A value of type '?' cannot be used as a default parameter because
> there are no standard conversions to type 'T'

Is there a way to implement similar "Raise property changed" in VS2015?

```
 public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        // Property        
        public const string SelectedItemPropertyName = "SelectedItem";

        private int? _selectedItem;       
        public int? SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(SelectedItemPropertyName, ref _selectedItem, value);
            }
        }

        // Method
        private void Load()
        {
            int number = SelectedItem ?? -1;

            // do your work
        }


       // Raise property changed
        public override void RaisePropertyChanged<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null, T oldValue = default, T newValue = default, bool broadcast = false)
        {
            base.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName, oldValue, newValue, broadcast);
            if (propertyName == nameof(SelectedItem))
                Load();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the implementations of `Set` and `base.RaisePropertyChanged` please? Without them we can only guess as to how they work. With my current guess, everything compiles

Comment: sorry, I don't understand completely what you meant. As a side note: I used mvvm light (latest version) for property implementation. This code works perfectly in VS2019.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a C# version under 7.1. In that case, you will need to use `default(T)`, rather than simply `default`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) is a link to the docs on default value expressions.